# How did we get from this to this? (TNB Frames and Calculus Question)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

Edit Fixed a typo: I am looking at a teachers notes and I see the following:

$$N = x'' – (x''\cdot T)T = x'' – \frac12 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} (T•T)T = x’'$$

I don't see how $(x'' \cdot T)T$ becomes

$$\frac12 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(T•T)T$$

Can someone help me understand this? Thanks in advance

I understand that the $\frac12 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ will go to $0$ which is why we just get an answer of $x''$ but I don't see how we get the middle step.

Comment: What is this?:  $•’$

Comment: I have no idea, it's how the problem is written.

Comment: Fixed the typo @mjw

Comment: Can you link us a picture of the teacher's notes?

Comment: The pair of symbols (•') appears again a couple of lines down.  Also a typo?

Comment: What is TNB frame?  What is $T$, the unit tangent vector?

Comment: I figured it out, it's just realizing that (x'•x) is (1/2)(d/dx)(x•x). In this case T•T is 1. So the derivative vanishes making it 0. The typo is what was messing me up.

Comment: In this case x" is T', so you get (T'•T) which follows along with the formula above. And yes, T is the unit tangent vector.

Comment: So even if you have an arclength-parametrized curve (which means that $x'$ is the unit vector $T$), the equation is wrong. $x''$ will not in general be a unit vector, and $N$ is a unit vector. Indeed, this is where curvature comes in: $x'' = \kappa N$.

Comment: Yes, the next part explained that if you forced N to be a unit vector you get x''/||x"| and we define |x"| to be the curvature. I was just confused on the part with (1/2)(d/dt)(T•T) coming from (X"•T)

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a rather odd question, but one nevertheless oddly engaging.  In an effort to understand curves satisfying the OPs hypothesis (see (7) below), I tried to develop a few of its implications.  It is my hope that others with curiosity similar to mine will find the following "analysis" helpful.

Assuming $x(t)$ is a regular curve, by definition,

$\dfrac{ds}{dt} = \vert x' \vert \ne 0, \tag 1$

where $s$ is the arc-length along $x(t)$; then

$x' = \dfrac{ds}{dt}T, \tag 2$

$T$ being the unit tangent field to $x(t)$; differentiating (2) with respect to $t$,

$x'' = \dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2} T + \dfrac{ds}{dt} \dfrac{dT}{dt}; \tag 3$

in the usual manner the chain rule yields

$\dfrac{dT}{dt} = \dfrac{ds}{dt} \dfrac{dT}{ds}; \tag 4$

the first Frenet-Serret equation,

$\dfrac{dT}{ds} = \kappa N, \tag 5$

is valid provided $\kappa$, the curvature of $x(t)$, does not vanish, and serves to define $N$, the unit normal field to $x(t)$; *via* (4) and (5), (3) becomes

$x'' = \dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2}T + \left (\dfrac{ds}{dt} \right )^2 \kappa N. \tag 6$

We oberve that (1)-(4) apply to any regular curve $x(t)$, and (5) and (6) as well when $\kappa$ does not vanish, which in accord with (1), (4) and (5) is true provided that

$\dfrac{dT}{dt} \ne 0; \tag{6.5}$

if in addition $x(t)$ satisfies the given hypothesis

$N = x'' - (x'' \cdot T)T = x'' - \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt}(T \cdot T)T, \tag 7$

then

$(x'' \cdot T)T = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt}(T \cdot T)T, \tag 8$

whence

$x'' \cdot T = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt}(T \cdot  T) = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt}(1) = 0; \tag 9$

in light of (6) we find

$\dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2} = \dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2}T \cdot T + \left (\dfrac{ds}{dt} \right )^2 \kappa N \cdot T = x'' \cdot T = 0; \tag{10}$

thus

$\dfrac{ds}{dt} = v, \text{a constant}, \tag{11}$

that is, $x(t)$ is a *constant-speed curve*; hence we may write

$s(t) = v(t - t_0) + s_0, \tag{12}$

where

$s_0 = s(t_0); \tag{13}$

furthermore, *via* (9), equation (7) becomes

$N = x''; \tag{14}$

combining this with (6) and (10) we find

$N = \left (\dfrac{ds}{dt} \right )^2 \kappa N, \tag{15}$

from which we infer

$\left (\dfrac{ds}{dt} \right )^2 \kappa = 1, \tag{16}$

that is,

$\kappa = \left(\dfrac{ds}{dt} \right )^{-2} = v^{-2} = \dfrac{1}{v^2}; \tag{17}$

note that (1) and (11) imply

$v \ne 0. \tag{18}$

We may also take this line one or two steps further and develop an expression for the torsion $\tau$ of $x(t)$ in terms of $v$ and $x'(t)$, $x''(t)$, and $x'''(t)$.  Said torsion may be defined *via* the third Frenet-Serret equation

$\dfrac{dB}{ds} = -\tau N, \tag{19}$

where the *unit binormal vector* $B$ is defined through

$B = T \times N; \tag{20}$

from (2) and (11) we have

$T = \dfrac{dt}{ds} x' = v^{-1}x'; \tag{21}$

thus, substituting this and (14) into (20),

$B = v^{-1}x' \times x''; \tag{22}$

thus

$\dfrac{dB}{ds} = \dfrac{dt}{ds}\dfrac{dB}{dt} = v^{-1}\dfrac{d}{dt}(v^{-1}x' \times x'')$
$= v^{-2}(x'' \times x'' + x' \times x''') = v^{-2}(x' \times x'''); \tag{23}$

in light of this equation and (14), (19) becomes

$v^{-2}(x' \times x''') = -\tau x'', \tag{24}$

or

$\tau x'' = -v^{-2}(x' \times x'''); \tag{25}$

now (14) implies $x''$ is a unit vector, whence

$\tau = \tau x'' \cdot x'' = -v^{-2}(x' \times x''') \cdot x''$
$= v^{-2}(x''' \times x') \cdot x'' = v^{-2}(x' \times x'') \cdot x''', \tag{26}$

where we have used [standard vector algebra][1] to effect these re-arrangements.  We may re-express this result *via* (14) and (21):

$\tau =  v^{-2}(x' \times x'') \cdot x''' = v^{-1}(v^{-1}x' \times x'') \cdot x'''$
$= v^{-1}(T \times N) \cdot x''' = v^{-1} B \cdot x'''. \tag{27}$

Our OP Nono4271 posed the specific question, "how $(x'' \cdot T)T$ becomes $\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(T \cdot T)T$?" it is evident that

$(x'' \cdot T)T = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt}(T \cdot T)T \tag{28}$

if and only if

$x'' \cdot T = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt}(T \cdot T) = T' \cdot T, \tag{29}$

which is evidently a consequence of

$x'' = T'; \tag{30}$

inspection of (3) reveals that this holds when

$\dfrac{ds}{dt} = 1, \; \dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2} = 0, \tag{31}$

that is, when $ds/dt$ is contant, and in fact

$s = t + c \tag{32}$

for some constant $c$; thus $t$ is essentially the arc-length along $x(t)$.  Indeed, (32) implies

$\dfrac{ds}{dt} = 1, \; \dfrac{dt}{ds} = 1, \tag{33}$

whence

$x'(t) = \dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{dt}{ds}\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{dx}{ds} = T(t), \tag{34}$

and

$x''(t) = T'(t), \tag{35}$

as required above *ca.* (30).

Returning momentarily to (7), suppose for the moment that $V$ is *any* unit vector field along the curve $x(t)$, and set

$M =  x'' - (x'' \cdot V)V; \tag {36}$

then $M$ is a vector field along $x(t)$, orthogonal to $V$, for

$M \cdot V = x'' \cdot V - (x'' \cdot V)V \cdot V = x'' \cdot V - x'' \cdot V = 0, \tag{37}$

since

$V \cdot V = 1; \tag{38}$

if in addition we choose

$V = T, \tag{39}$

we find that $M$ is normal to the curve $x(t)$; but it is not necessarily *the* normal $N$ given by (5); as such, the mere existence of such $M$ is not in and of itself a rich source of information concerning the curve $x(t)$; the specific hypothesis that $M = N$, however, allows specific inferences concerning the nature of $x(t)$ to be drawn, since it imposes significant restrictions on both $T$ and $N$.

It may very well be possible to derive further properties of these curves $x(t)$, but we have in fact found their curvature (17) and torsion (27), so perhaps this is a good enough place to leave off.